# Test whether $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy or NOT

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

> Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of reals such that $\displaystyle |x_n-x_{n+1}|<\frac{1}{n^2}$ for all $n=1,2,\dots$. Prove or disprove that $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$.

We have $$|x_n-x_{n+p}|\le |x_n-x_{n+1}|+\cdots +|x_{n+p-1}-x_{n+p}|<\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{(n+1)^2}+\cdots+\frac1{(n+p-1)^2}$$
which implies that $|x_n-x_{n+p}|<\frac p{n^2}$. If $p=n^2$ then $|x_n-x_{n+p}|<1$. From here I guess $\{x_n\}$ need not be Cauchy in $\Bbb R$. But I'm unable to find a suitable example where I can show that $|x_n-x_{n+p}|>\text{something}$.

I want some hints..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your upper bound for $|x_n-x_{n+p}|$ is good! Note that for $n>1$,
$$\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{(n+1)^2}+\cdots+\frac1{(n+p-1)^2}\leq \frac1{n(n-1)}+\frac1{n(n+1)}+\cdots+\frac1{(n+p-2)(n+p-1)}\\=\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+p-1}<\frac{1}{n-1}$$
where the second sum is telescopic.
Now it should be easy to finish the job.

Answer (score 5):

$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac 1 {k^{2}} \to 0$ as $ n \to \infty$ because $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {k^{2}} <\infty$. Hence the sequence is Cauchy.